# Storing Current Items From Comboboxes in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, combobox, slider

I have a simple program that makes shapes of different sizes and colours.

The shapes and colours are selected from ComboBoxes, while the size is controlled by a slider. I want to store the -currently selected- shape, size and the colour **in an ArrayList of a new class that I defined** by pressing a button and then print the info pressing another.

```
private ArrayList<ShapeItem> ShapeItem;


    slider = new JSlider (JSlider.HORIZONTAL,minValue,maxValue,initValue);
    add(slider);
    slider.addChangeListener(this);


    // Instantiate a new ComboBox with options for Shape
    shapeChoice = new JComboBox();
    shapeChoice.addItem("Point");
    shapeChoice.addItem("Square");
    shapeChoice.addItem("Circle");
    shapeChoice.addItem("Doughnut");
    shapeChoice.addItem("Pentagon");
    shapeChoice.addItem("Hexagon");
    add(shapeChoice); // Add the JComboBox to the JPanel
    shapeChoice.addActionListener(this);  //Register the JComboBox selection with Java

    // Instantiate a new ComboBox with options for Colour
    colorChoice = new JComboBox();
    colorChoice.addItem("Black");
    colorChoice.addItem("Red");
    colorChoice.addItem("Green");
```

Then:

```
readItems = new JButton("Read values");
    add(readItems);
    readItems.addActionListener(this);

    printItems = new JButton("List all values");
    add(printItems);
    printItems.addActionListener(this);

ShapeItem = new ArrayList<ShapeItem>();
```

My best bet at achieving that was introducting

```
if (e.getSource() == readItems)
    {
       String item0 = shapeChoice.getSelectedItem();
       String item1 = colorChoice.getSelectedItem(); 


    }

    // if the "List all values" button is pressed    
    else if (e.getSource() == printItems)
    {
        // loop through the ArrayList of items prnting each one out in turn to the JTextArea
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
           textOutput.append(itemList.get(j).shapeChoose + "\n");
           textOutput.append(itemList.get(j).colourChoose + "\n");
           textOutput.append("\n");
        }
    }
```

**But at the**

String item0 = shapeChoice.getSelectedItem();

I get an "incompatible types error"

The new class I made is this:

```
public class ShapeItem
```

{

```
public String shapeChoose;
public String colorChoose;
public int thesize;
```

}

Am I trying the right way or there is another method to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shortcut, you'll have to iterate through the items in the `JComboBox` and add each of them to the array.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Main {
        JComboBox<String> shapeChoice = new JComboBox<>();
        shapeChoice.addItem("Point");
        shapeChoice.addItem("Square");
        shapeChoice.addItem("Circle");
        shapeChoice.addItem("Doughnut");
        shapeChoice.addItem("Pentagon");
        shapeChoice.addItem("Hexagon");
        System.out.println(combo2Array(shapeChoice).toString());
    }
    public static List<String> combo2Array(JComboBox<String> combo){

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<combo.getItemCount();i++){
            list.add(combo.getItemAt(i));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Output:

> [Point, Square, Circle, Doughnut, Pentagon, Hexagon]

You can also change it to generics, if you want (it doesn't have to be Strings). 
But the idea will be the same.

I made what I believe is the design you are looking for and posted it on [gist](https://gist.github.com/kyllopardiun/5d060ff37a0bc43e30e7).
But it will be an awful design choice, as you are creating a list with a size much larger than what you actually need. **Using 3 Lists (one for each component) will be a better design choice and that's why I will not update my answer here with the [gist code](https://gist.github.com/kyllopardiun/5d060ff37a0bc43e30e7).**

**EDIT2:**

To add just what is currently selected:

```
public void addSelected2List(){
    ShapeItem shape = new ShapeItem();
    shape.setShapeChoose((String)shapeChoice.getSelectedItem());
    shape.setColourChoose((String)colourChoice.getSelectedItem());
    shape.setSize((int)sizeChoice.getSelectedItem());
    list.add(shape);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
I guess my title is a bit misleading, because I would like to get an output of
'[Shape, Size, Color]'
for my current values though,
for example
'[Circle, 57, Black]'

Comment: @Pippo, your question is very unclear and my answer is to part of your question i.e *"how to make a List with the same elements as the ones in the JComboBox"*. It will be very hard to help you further without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ,I'm afraid I am unable to simplify the program/problem but here's another attempt at explaining the situation:
-I implemented ChangeListener and ActionListener
-I introduced a new class that contains the ArrayList
-My program has two comboboxes and a slider.
-I have a "Read Values" button
-When this button is pressed, I want the currently selected size value from the slider to be stored in the ArrayList. I want the currently selected combobox selections to be stored in the ArrayList too.

I hope it's clearer, if not, thank you for taking the time to answer anyway!

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you a lot! No need to post the 3 list design!
Thank you very much!